# Derivation of quantum scattering of 1D square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, scattering

[image]

The above is the question. In my book, I'm given this formula for calculating the transmission probability (when E>V_nought):

[image]

Here, k1 = sqrt(2m(E-V_0))/h_bar

However, the problem is that this formula is derived based on the following diagram:

[image]

Clearly, the diagram in my original question is upside down, and "k1" in the question would be k1 = sqrt(2m(V_o - E))/h_bar. My question is do we have to re-derive a different expression for the probability, or do we just use the same one but use the correct value for k1 depending on how the potential step is drawn. Also, if the particle was moving from right to left, would we need a new formula for that as well?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE. You can (and should) use [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1) notation for math.

Answer (score 1):

It is more convenient, and in theory also more appropriate to calculate both the transmission and reflection coefficients, $T$ and $R$. Since $|T|^2 + |R|^2 = 1$, we will have $|T| = 1$ if and only if $R=0$. So instead of checking that the squares of real and imaginary parts of T add up to one, it is much easier just to check that R=0, and usually you will not need to do it separately for the real and imaginary parts!

You should go ahead and compute R and T for YOUR problem instead of looking to use the answer from another textbook, since your professor probably expects you to be able to that yourself. But, just to make your life a little easier, let give you a hint: the answer is the same but flip the sign of $V_0$, i.e. you will have $E+V_0$ instead of $E-V_0$ there in the denominator.

Comment: how come in the denominator they didn't write k1 as well? If they wrote it as E-V_0, doesnt that mean its always like that?

Comment: on an exam its not possible to find the expression because the algebra is just too long and tedious. Thats why Im looking for  a formula

Comment: The sign of $E_0$ will flip in the definition of k1 also!
anyway, this was just a hint, you should calculate everything yourself, long and tedious and all. Then you will get an A at the exam because nothing will seem too long and tedious anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly, the diagram in my original question is upside down, and "k1" in the question would be k1 = sqrt(2m(V_o - E))/h_bar.

This is because the image you have attached is of a rectangular potential barrier. and the value of K1 is $\sqrt(2m(V_0 - E)/ℏ)$ for $E<V_0$ not greater than $V_0$, that you have stated above. And yes the transmission probability for both the Rectangular barrier and and Finite potential well are different. You can clearly notice that from the formula of  both the transmission probabilities. For illuminating discussion on the potential barrier problem kindly visit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier).

**Explaining the answer of (b)**
If you notice the Transmission coefficient, You will find out that the 'Transmission Probability' becomes unity (**the well becomes transparent**) when the sine term is zero, which is to say when $2a/ℏ*{sqrt(2m(E_n + V_0))} = n\pi$, when n= any integer.
The energies for perfect transmission is hence given by

$E_n+V_0 = \frac{(n^2)(\pi^2)(ℏ^2)}{2m(2a)^2}$

These are the discrete energy spectrum for which the transmission probability is one. That means the well is totally transparent.

[image: Transmission coeff. as a function of energy]

Hope it helped :)